# xcode 10: how to open swift code use "open quickly (shift+command+O)"?

Tags: swift, xcode10

in the swift project, i use "open quickly (shift+command+O)" to open swift declare file, but always open Objective-c file, how can I open swift declare file?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't metter on the programming language, but it metters on the editor.

So in Xcode you can use
**Shift + Command + O**
for Open Quickly

now if you want to open just Swift files you can add **.swift** extension behind file name. This search just in Swift files.

[image]

Comment: when i use open quickly to open file, i want to see swift file, but always open objective-c file

Comment: @Guo do you want to see Objective-C file as Swift file?